# what is the output if x == 42

Tags: c++

```
switch (x % 5)
{
case 0: cout << x++ << '';
   case 1: cout << x-- << '';
   break;
case 2: cout << ++x << '';
case 3: cout << --x << '';
default: cout << 2*x << '';

}
```

Comment: Did you try? What did you get?

Comment: Compile and run it, and you'll see. There should be a `break` keyword in the `case 2` and `case 3` lines.

Comment: This reeks of being an interview question or homework...

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Is it really necessary to have breaks inside case?? Perhaps the program was coded to be that way.

Comment: In fact, this question was already flagged earlier...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196775/what-is-the-output-of-x-in-this-part-of-c-fragment

Comment: Please do _not_ repost questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196775/what-is-the-output-of-x-in-this-part-of-c-fragment . Or are you going to post one for every possible value of `x`? That's going to become a little tedious long before you get to the roughly 4-billion limit.

Answer (score 1):

Since `''` is an empty character constant, you will get an error. So there will be no output from the program.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: +1. There won't be any output from the program because it won't compile.

Comment: Hm, given the complete rewrite of the answer, my above comment is rendered obsolete :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation:

if x is 42, x%5 = 2.
Therefore, case 2 will be executed. Since there is no break, case 3 and default will also be executed.

Therefore output is:

```
43 42 84
```

Comment: Output should actually be 434284

Comment: Looks like there isn't a space, only ''. I guess the numeric output matters more.

Comment: `''` is an error, actually - you aren't supposed to use empty char literals.

Answer (score 0):

43, 42, 84 when compiled and run on my machine.

Looks like homework ¬_¬

You hit case two and then drop through hitting case 3 and default due to the absence of breaks;

Comment: If that compiled on your machine, your compiler is deficient.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepad.org/asP1EbPw - was it so difficult to check it?

Comment: Was it so difficult to check the actual program given, rather than one you appear to have written yourself? :-)

Comment: The "actual program given" contains errors and will not compile at all.

Answer (score -1):

You must put a

```
break;
```

at the end of each case. If you don't do this your x var will have a weird value because enter in two or more switch's cases.

Comment: What makes you so certain that is not the intended behavior? Also, this isn't even an answer to the question of "what is the if the output of x if its 42".